# Django - How to manage many messages?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently searching for a way to properly manage messages I show the user, as a have a lot of them, for example at my views.py:

```
messages.error(request, 'You cannot do this bla bla')
```

I also have in mind to make the site multi-language. So how do you guys solve this?
Do you simply setup a messages.py and reference stuff at views.py or is there maybe a more elegeant way that also has multi-langauge implementation in mind?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/ ?

Comment: Easy, thanks for the hint. I wasn't aware that django already has this kind of management build-in